# How can I compose a list of option flags and pass them to a command in Fish Shell?

Tags: docker-compose, fish

Since Docker Compose supports [multiple Compose files](https://docs.docker.com/compose/extends/#multiple-compose-files), I want to detect all such files in the current directory and pass them to Docker Compose instead of needing to specify all of them manually. In Bash, I can accomplish this via:

```bash
docker compose $(for file in *.yml; do echo "-f $file "; done) up -d
```

I can produce the same list of *flags* in Fish with the following one-liner:

```
for file in *.yml; echo -n -- "-f $file "; end
```

I have tried various ways of passing that list to `docker compose`, including the following:

```
docker compose (for file in *.yml; echo -n -- "-f $file "; end) up -d
```

… but no matter how I try, I always get the following error:

```
stat /home/myuser/ compose-service1.yml -f compose-service2.yml -f compose-service3.yml -f compose-service4.yml -f compose-service5.yml: no such file or directory
```

My questions are:

1. What must be done to ensure the list of option flags are passed to `docker compose` without problems?
2. Is there another, saner approach, preferably even more concise than the (admittedly and obviously broken) approach I've taken above?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Fish splits command substitutions on newlines only.**

You are using `echo -n`, which explicitly doesn't add a newline. So your option printing code

```
for file in *.yml; echo -n -- "-f $file "; end
```

ends up printing something like

> -f compose-service1.yml -f compose-service2.yml -f compose-service3.yml -f compose-service4.yml -f compose-service5.yml

As one line, which, to fish, is one argument. It ends up running like (truncated)

```
docker compose "-f compose-service1.yml -f compose-service2.yml..." up -d
```

So docker tries to find one file called

```
 compose-service1.yml -f compose-service2.yml -f compose-service3.yml -f compose-service4.yml -f compose-service5.yml
```

(with the leading space!)

Unlike bash, fish doesn't split this on spaces. This is generally a good idea, because people use filenames that include spaces. Your bash example is broken if a .yml file has spaces in the name.

But because you *want* each `-f` and each filename to be a separate argument to `docker compose`, you need to ensure that the `-f` and the filename end up on separate lines.

```
for file in *.yml; printf '%s\n' -f $file; end
```

or

```
for file in *.yml; string join \n -- -f $file; end
```

is probably the simplest way to do that. This would print

```
-f
compose-service1.yml
-f
compose-service2.yml
-f
compose-service3.yml
-f
compose-service4.yml
-f
compose-service5.yml
```

which fish would then turn into one argument per line.

---

Alternatively:

Docker's option parsing is reasonably standard, so you can also pass a compose file as `-fcompose.yml`, directly attached to the `-f` option. (this also explains your error - docker sees a `-f` and then uses the rest of the argument as the filename)

That would allow using `echo`:

```
for file in *.yml; echo -- "-f$file"; end
```

This just prepends the `-f` and then prints it *with a newline* (no `echo -n`), which ends up printing

```
-fcompose-service1.yml
-fcompose-service2.yml
```

(and so on)

---

As an aside, if you really really really need a command substitution to be split on spaces, you can use `string split " "`. This is common with pkg-config and other `*-config` tools inspired by it.

```
pkg-config --cflags --libs gio-2.0
```

prints (truncated as an example)

> -pthread -I/usr/include/libmount -I/usr/include/blkid -I/usr/include/glib-2.0

which is meant to be used as-if copy-pasted into the commandline. (this means that pkg-config paths can't include spaces, btw)

In that case you would use

```
g++ example_01.cpp (pkg-config --cflags --libs gio-2.0 | string split -n " ")
```

(the `-n`/`--no-empty` flag makes it ignore empty elements, which effectively means it treats runs of spaces as one thing).

So, if you wanted to re-do your bash command like it is, with broken spaces in filenames, you could also use

```
docker compose (for file in *.yml; echo -n -- "-f $file "; end | string split -n " ") up -d
```

Comment: I can't thank you enough, Fabian, for this detailed and thoughtful answer to my question. Much appreciated. I ended up with the following, which works wonderfully: `docker compose (for f in *.yml; echo -- "-f$f"; end) up -d`

Answer (score 1):

I'd do

```
for f in *.yml; set opts $opts "-f" $f; end
docker compose $opts up d
```

Suppose you have 10 files. The `opts` list will have 20 entries. Then the docker compose command receives the -f option and the file as separate parameters.

Comment: A good solution to use in a script, to be sure. Many thanks for the answer, Glenn! 

Answer (score 1):

The `for` loop, whilst perfectly fine, isn't strictly necessary:

```
fs=*.yml docker compose {-f,$fs} up -d
```

Comment: This works well and is quite short. Bravo, Chris! (Fellow So-Cal native, with Hoosier parents. )